# Open 3DXML files in browser using ASP.NET 2008

Tags: asp.net

We have 3DXML files in IIS6.0 virtual directory; we wanted to open those on browser using ASP.NET 2008, when user click on a button. How could we do that, any idea!

Thanks

Comment: You need button? Or link is also acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at this [3D XML viewer](http://www.3ds.com/products/3dvia/3d-xml/1/).

It has a standalone and browser component.